# SOIL image library and freeing memory

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I'm trying to write a class using soil to encapsulate SOIL calls. I can't however find any other means of deleting the memory if I load the image using

```
SOIL_load_OGL_texture
```

So what's the correct way to clean up after this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns OGL texture identifier

```
/* load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture */
GLuint tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
        "img.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
```

so it should be freed using OGL functions:

```
glDeleteTextures( 1, &tex_2d );
```

I have not used this lib, but this is what I would do

Comment: I think it's important to mention, that the returned value is the texture ID which you require to make actual use of the texture with OpenGL. So you must not delete the texture until you no longer need it for rendering. Also you should not recreate and delete textures each and every frame.